# DateTimePicker tab between fields

Tags: delphi

Is there anyway to allow the user to tab between the fields in the TDateTimePicker.

Having to use arrow keys or the mouse to position is very slow.

Comment: How will the user get to the next control?

Comment: @David - Go to the next control when you're on the last field. Not that I have the faintest idea how to do it, nor I see any point in showing any effort since both the arrow keys and the tab key are on the keyboard.

Comment: @sertac I guess you need a few presses of the arrow keys to move through the digits to the next field. Does CTRL+arrow do the trick?

Comment: @David - Both for ctrl+arrow and only arrow it takes only one click to go to the next field with the stock datetimepicker, the control selects the field you land on.

Comment: @Sertac in other words this is pointless. Arrows already do what is desired.

Comment: Not only do arrow do it but so does the period. This works pretty well when using the number pad but for people that are used to tabbing between fields you have to shift gears.   Thanks all for the attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way.

Interception of the <kbd>TAB</kbd> and sending a right arrow key <kbd>-></kbd> instead is easy, but then you have to decide when to let (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-)<kbd>TAB</kbd> trough, which should be done when standing on the first or last field in order to preserve normal user experience.

Now, all the selection changes from cursor and mouse events are internally handled within the Windows DTM control, and the Windows API does not support retrieving the separate fields. All you can acquire is the entire text of this very special *edit* control.

In theory you could intercept and save áll keyboard and mouse input, and calculate whether the first or last field is selected, but it will be a daunting and an error-prone task, and you should not want to.

Thus no. You just have to get yourself familiarized with it.

Comment: I guess I will just have to write my own using individual fields.  Thank you.